# How do I define the size of a ggplot plot output inside a function for use in rmarkdown documents?

Tags: r, ggplot2, r-markdown

I'm creating a custom package for theming my organization's ggplot and rmarkdown outputs to save us time and repeated work. I've managed to successfully create functions for setting our organizational colors,  palettes, gradients, and plot themes. As it stands right now, we can use `ggplot() + theme_ofda()` to ensure all our plots meet our organizational design standards, so that's good!

What I'm trying to do now is create a function to create the document title in our standard format. I'd like to use `ggplot()` to do this so our rmarkdown outputs can portable to any output format without needing to create a custom `.CSS` or `preamble.tex` file [since I'm not super comfortable creating in either format].

The title format we use for our reports should look like the following [just a purple background spanning most of the document width with white text for the title itself]:

[image]

I started by creating a new function in my package called `ofda_heading()`. This calls on a previous function created, called `mps_cols()` which is just a list of our organizational colors and associated hex values.

```
ofda_heading <- function(htitle = "Some Title", pri.color = mps_cols("wine")) {
  ggplot() +
    geom_blank() +
    labs(title = htitle) +
    theme(
      # Specific text definitions
      plot.title = element_text(size = 22.5, family = "Segoe UI Semibold", face = "bold", hjust = 0.5, colour = "white"),
      # Plot aesthetics
      plot.background = element_rect(fill = pri.color, color = pri.color),
      plot.margin = margin(.125, .125, .125, .125, unit = "inches"),
      # Panel aesthetics
      panel.background = element_blank()
    )
}
```

When I call `ofda_heading(htitle = "My Spoon Is Too Big!")`, I get pretty much what I'm expecting to see:

[image]

What I don't understand is how to change the `ggplot()` output to have a height of the title itself plus the `plot.margin()` assigned in the function. The function is creating a full-size plot without a plot. I understand it's possible with `ggsave()`, but I'm not looking to save this to disk, since this will be part of rmarkdown reports.

So, all this said, the basic question: What do I need to do to my new function to make the output only be the size of the title plus the margins when knitted into an rmarkdown document **without** needing our staff to remember to specify chunk options in rmarkdown? If `ggplot()` is incapable of doing this, are there other ways of achieving what I am looking for without creating custom `.CSS` or `preamble.tex` files? I need this to be a function that anyone in my org can call to create the title of the report they're working on.

**EDIT**: Okay, thinking about this a little bit more... Maybe I'm just dumb, since I've only recently started using r markdown, but I could specify a title chunk in a custom r markdown template, right? Use the chunk option to set the plot size and still call the new `ofda_heading()` function as-is? What would I need to do to the chunk options to get that to work, if that is indeed the solution?

Comment: Are the Rmarkdown reports being compiled to PDF or HTML? I think a custom CSS or tex-based solution might be much simpler--and could be invoked as easily as calling an R function.

Comment: The reports could be compiled as either, which is part of my problem and why I wanted to use `ggplot()` as it would be robust to either format.

Comment: An R function could potentially detect what the output format is and spit out CSS or TeX code accordingly. Or perhaps there's a template that could be used. And that would have the advantage of being actual text, rather than a PNG image of a ggplot...

Comment: @GregorThomas I certainly wouldn't be against that sort of solution, though to be honest, I would have no idea where to begin to implement it. I've been reading up on how to create the custom CSS and TeX files necessary to generate what I'm looking for, and... well, I'm hitting a wall with my ability to process the info I'm getting at this point.

Comment: If I were you, I'd re-ask the question focused on your problem, not on this partial solution. "How do I create a custom document title in an Rmd document that is easy for users and works for both HTML and PDF output?" By all means, include your `ggplot` attempt as a start on one possible method, but I think you'll get responses from Rmarkdown document experts if you make it clear that is the focus of the issue.

Comment: @GregorThomas That makes sense, thank you! I'll do that. :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved, for anyone silly enough to try to use a `ggplot` as a title or whatever like I'm trying to do. One can use the knitr chunk options to take care of this pretty easily, it turns out.

```
#Define the title/header function in the package:
ofda_heading <- function(title = "Some Title", pri.color = mps_cols("wine")) {
  ggplot() +
    geom_blank() +
    labs(title = title) +
    theme(
      # Specific text definitions
      plot.title = element_text(size = 22.5, family = "Segoe UI Semibold", face = "bold", hjust = 0.5, colour = "white"),
      # Plot aesthetics
      plot.background = element_rect(fill = pri.color, color = pri.color),
      plot.margin = margin(.25, .125, .125, .125, unit = "inches"),
      # Panel aesthetics
      panel.background = element_blank()
    )
}
```

Once that's been defined and the package has been loaded, use the knitr chunk options `fig.height`, `fig.width`, and `fig.align` in your `.Rmd` document to mess with the output a bit:

````
```{r title_chunk, fig.height=.5, fig.width=8, fig.align='center'}
ofda_heading()
```
````

This seems to solve my problem for now, though I know it's a stopgap until I can buckle down and learn both `css` and `LaTeX` to do this whole thing properly.